# Simple proxy program with BOOST

Tags: c++, boost

I'm trying to do a very simple program. It's actually a proxy, that I need to connect to it and that proxy fowards the packets to the outter world.

I think of making a list of incomming packets, change the incomming port to a new port, forward the packet and wait for a response, and get the port number for the packet from my list and send it back to my app...

How can I do that with boost??? I don't need the complete source code, just  some code and the directions to start...(althought the full code will be usefull hehehe)...

Thx.

Comment: Tried your hand at `boost::asio`?

Comment: Yeah, but i stucked... How can I get the incomming packet, change source port and forward it??? I see some things about sockets and services..

Comment: Are you trying to built a proxy (so you usually know which protocol you're handling) or essentially a network bridge/filter that is forwarding any sort of network packet.

Comment: hmmmm... i'm building a bridge...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in over your head, have you considered not coding it? Use [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/):

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:7656,bind=internal-ip,fork TCP:external-host:7656
```